# How can I use PHP to display a variable every other day at a certain time?

Tags: php, date, time

**Context**

I would like to use PHP to change out content in HTML every other day. I can currently achieve this, however, I would need the content to change at 7:00 AM PST. Right now, I'm essentially subtracting the current `time` from a set point in time using `mktime` and rounding down. A simple `if` statement takes care of the variable.

**The Code**

```
<?php

$first_date = mktime(7,0,0,1,1,2014);
$second_date = time();

$offset = $second_date-$first_date;

$this_day = floor($offset/60/60/24);

if ($this_day % 2 == 0) {

    //do something

} else {

    //do something else

}

?>
```

Like I stated before, the code is working however it is not changing at 7:00 AM PST. I tried adjusting the start time in $first_date however it didn't seem to help. I think I am missing something regarding actual timezones and how the time is being calculated. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just take the start date and gave it a timezone, then checked the day number of the year. If it's even and 7am or later, do something. Otherwise, do something else. The only issue you will have is New Years. This may show the same content two days in a row.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

if ($date->format('z') % 2 == 0 && $date->format('h') >= 7) {

    //do something

} else {

    //do something else

}

?>
```